# Get the publish location or publishing folder location

Tags: vb.net

I know that

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

can get the installation folder.

But how can I get the location of publishing folder that I put in "PUBLISH" tab of my project? say.. (of course this will not work)

```
Application.PublishingPath
```

I am just trying to get the manifest file there so that I could know the current version number of the application inside the publishing folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just manually store the publishing path to a variable..

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer..

```
Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation
```

thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri
```

Comment: no it does not give me the right path for publish or updatelocation, it only shows the executablepath

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila EDIT: Try the new one

Comment: this gives an error when my project is not the same with the one installed